# Why Does Agora.io v4 web sdk have an echo?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I just installed the v4 web sdk, and when run the meeting i hear an echo. Its not an issue when i use headphones, which is okay. But when i dint use one, i hear an echo which is persistent.  I have used other platforms like Google, Zoom, Web-ex, Blue jeans. etc. But I never had this issue. What am i doing wrong?

I looked into the Agora FAQ, but that was not helpful. I have contacted support, but haven't heard anything yet other than the headphone use.

I have tried everything in this section - https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/audio_noaudio

Best,
Vig

Answer (score 0):

To remove noise/echo you can use these properties AEC, ANS. It helps you in improving audio.

```
await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({
        AEC: true, ANS: true
      });
```